# How do RSS readers interact with advertisements?

Tags: rss, blogging, advertisements

Ok, I'm gonna start by saying I love RSS feeds, and I use my RSS reader to keep up with just about everything I read. Lately I've been wondering though, if the feeds are totally ad-free, am I actually not helping the website when I read its feed instead of going directly to the site?

In other words, when I read a post through my RSS reader, am I giving the respective site the pageviews it needs to profit from ads? Or am I reading the post without giving anything in return?

I'm asking this 'cause there are a couple of blogs I follow that I make point of giving them pageviews on good posts.

Thanks

Comment: You did mean "ad(s)" instead of "adds", right?

Comment: @Hello21: Yes, I apologize and am terribly ashamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot possibly speak for every web site out there. They're all different, and very well might be set up for it. But as a general rule of thumb, no. Viewing rss feeds does not count towards a site's page views.

For the most part, if you look to support a site you like, you'll actually have to click through and visit that site's page in your browser for it to do them any good. Possibly even click their ads instead of just viewing them if they use a pay-per-click model.